# LXC container to use "virtual" interface from host (namespace semantics)

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, lxc, namespace

So according to the documentation on the [Ubuntu LXC documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/lxc.html) the following statement can be found at the time of this writing:

> A NIC can only exist in one namespace at a time, **so a physical NIC passed into the container is not usable on the host**.

Now one can have a single physical network card (NIC) share several IPs like this in `/etc/network/interfaces` (Debian/Ubuntu):

```
auto eth0 eth0:1
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100/24
    gateway 192.168.0.1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.0.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The same can be done with the respective configuration on other distros as well.

Now the question: can `eth0` and `eth0:1` be assigned to different namespaces or will assigning either one limit the other to the same namespace automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to assign `eth0` and `eth0:1` to different namespaces, but keep in mind there are security implications because you are exposing physical network device to your container.

Because of that, I would just use `veth` and `bridge`. Create a bridge `br0` and bridge it with `eth0` device by default. Then configure your lxc container like this:

```
lxc.network.type=veth
lxc.network.ipv4=192.168.0.200
lxc.network.link=br0
```

This will have the same result, but you will use a virtual Ethernet interface for the container and you will also be able to access the same network that your LXC host is in because of the bridge.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the security implications, though?

Comment: One more thing. "Should" means you don't actually know and I need to try, or "should" means it should work on recent enough versions or so?

Comment: @0xC0000022L - always try but in this case it sounds like it's not 100% known.

Comment: @0xC0000022L should means that I don't actually know and you need to try it. The interfaces which are assigned to LXC guests art not visible from LXC Host usually. As it is same physical interface, you could expect different results. Regarding security, I know some cases that when you make host network devices usable in the container and also use upstart as init, `halt` in a container can shut down the host. This is the case with `none` network type.

Comment: @edvinas.me: `upstart`, yes. You're right. I remember now. Thanks.